# How to customize the BitDefender 2011 Parental Control blocked website page

Tags: webpage, parental-controls, bitdefender

Any idea how I can customize the webpage displayed when trying to access websites blocked through BitDefender 2011 Parental Controls?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to do to it? Your question is very general.

Comment: I am trying to change the text of the displayed page when a website is blocked.

Comment: OK, one more question: Is this the Bit Defender Total Security 2011, Bit Defender Internet Security 2011, or just the BitDefender
Antivirus Pro 2011. I intend to load up a copy to see if I can figure it out, but I want to get exactly what you have.

Comment: I think it's Internet Security, but both Total Security and Internet Security have parental controls. The AV version only has the AV I think. Thank you.